# Как удалить элемент в односвязном списке?

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Есть такое условие:

Разработать программу для  задачи  - сформировать однонаправленный список из вводимой строки. В поле каждого элемента списка записать отдельный символ. Если первый символ - буква "А", то в конец списка добавить еще одну букву "А", иначе из списка исключить все буквы "А". Вывести полученный результат.

С первым условием я справился и добавил еще одну букву в конец списка, а вот со вторым никак не могу. Мой код:

```
Node *pv = new Node;
char b;
pv = head;
if (pv->item != 'A') {
    while (pv->next != NULL) {
        if (pv->item == 'A') {
            delete pv;
        }
        pv = pv->next;
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что делать так сразу нельзя: delete pv. Но я просто не знаю, как решить эту задачу. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Удаляются так 1. Найти предыдущий елемент от заданого, 2. связать предыдущий елемент с следующим от заданого. Тогда цепочка будет без нарушений в памяти. Плюс ньюансы при нахождении заданого елемента в начале/конце списка.

Comment: @Денис  Покажите, как вы определили сам список.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так (не компилировал, так что огрехи могут быть; главное - сам принцип)...

```
pv = head;
if (pv->item != 'A') {  // Если первый - не А, исключить все А
    while (pv->next != NULL) 
    {
        while (pv->next && pv->next->item == 'A') // Пока следующий А,
        {
            Node * tmp = pv->next;                // Убираем его
            pv->next = pv->next->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        if (pv->next) pv = pv->next;    // Если не последний - цикл продолжаем
    }
}
else  // Первый А, так что добавить еще оди А в конец
{
    while (pv->next) pv = pv->next; // Выход на последний
    Node * tmp = new Node;
    tmp->next = 0;
    tmp->item = 'A';
    pv->next = tmp;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно вставлять элемент в конец списка, то такой односвязный список лучше всего делать двусторонним.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показана, как такой список может быть реализован

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char item;
        Node *next;
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

private:
    void delete_all()
    {
        while ( head )
        {
            Node *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }

        tail = head;
    }

    void copy_all( const Node *src_head )
    {
        for ( ; src_head; src_head = src_head->next )
        {
            push_back( src_head->item );
        }
    }

    std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        for ( Node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->item << ' ';
        }

        return os;
    }

public:
    //  constructors
    List() : head( nullptr ), tail( nullptr )
    {
    }

    List( const std::string &s ) : List()
    {
        for ( char c : s )
        {
            push_back( c );
        }
    }

    List( const List &lst ) : List()
    {
        copy_all( lst.head );
    }

    //  destructor
    ~List()
    {
        delete_all();
    }

    //  copy assignment operator
    List & operator =( const List &lst )
    {
        if ( this != &lst )
        {
            delete_all();
            copy_all( lst.head );
        }

        return *this;
    }

    //  methods
    void push_fron( char c )
    {
        head = new Node { c, head };
        if ( tail == nullptr ) tail = head;
    }

    void push_back( char c )
    {
        if ( tail == nullptr )
        {
            tail = new Node { c, nullptr };
            head = tail;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = new Node { c, nullptr };
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }

    void remove( char c )
    {
        for ( Node **current = &head; *current;  )
        {
            if( ( *current )->item == c )
            {
                Node *tmp = *current;
                *current = ( *current )->next;
                delete tmp;
                if ( *current == nullptr ) tail = nullptr;
            }
            else if ( ( *current )->next && ( *current )->next->item == c )
            {
                if ( tail == ( *current )->next ) tail = *current;
                Node *tmp = ( *current )->next;
                ( *current )->next = tmp->next;
                delete tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                current = &( *current )->next;
            }
        }
    }

    char front() const { return head->item; }
    char & front() { return head->item; }
    char  back() const { return tail->item; }
    char back() { return tail->item; }

    bool empty() const { return head == nullptr; }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const List &lst );
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const List &lst )
{
    return lst.out( os );
}

int main()
{
    List lst1( "ABC" );

    std::cout << lst1 << std::endl;

    if ( lst1.front() == 'A' ) lst1.push_back( 'A' );

    std::cout << lst1 << std::endl;

    List lst2( "BAAACA" );

    std::cout << lst2 << std::endl;

    if ( lst2.front() != 'A' ) lst2.remove( 'A' );

    std::cout << lst2 << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
A B C 
A B C A 
B A A A C A 
B C
```

Answer (score 0):

если можно использовать контейнеры из STL, а не придумывать свою реализацию списка, то можно как-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<char> l;
    char c, cmp_char = 'A';

    while ((c = std::cin.get()) != 'EOF') {
        l.push_back(c);
    }

    if (l.front() == cmp_char) {
        l.push_back(cmp_char);
    } else {
        l.remove(cmp_char);
    }

    for (std::list<char>::const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось немножко по другому: http://ideone.com/E1cpcz

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
  char key;
  Node *next;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Инициализация односвязанного списка из строки
// ----------------------------------------------------------

Node* FuncInit(const std::string &iStr) {
  Node* Res = nullptr;
  Node* Cur = nullptr;    
  for (const auto &i:iStr) {
    Node* Tmp = new Node({i,nullptr});
    if (Res) Cur->next = Tmp; else Res = Tmp;
    Cur = Tmp;  
  }
  return Res;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Разрушение односвязанного списка
// ----------------------------------------------------------

void FuncDestroy(Node* &iTop) {
  if (iTop) {
    Node *Tmp = iTop->next;
    FuncDestroy(Tmp);
    delete iTop;  
  }
  iTop = nullptr;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
    // Вставка символа в конец односвязанного списка
// ----------------------------------------------------------

void FuncBackInsert(Node* &iTop, const char iChar) {
  Node* Res = iTop;     
  Node* Tmp = new Node({iChar,nullptr});
  while(iTop && iTop->next) iTop=iTop->next;    
  if (iTop) iTop->next = Tmp; else Res = Tmp;
  iTop = Res;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Удаление найденного символа из односвязанного списка
// ----------------------------------------------------------

void FuncRemoveChar(Node* &iTop, const char iChar) {
  Node *Res = nullptr;
  Node *Prev = iTop;    
  while(iTop) {
    if (iTop->key == iChar) {
      Prev->next = iTop->next;
      delete iTop;
      iTop = Prev;  
    } else {
      if (!Res) Res = iTop;
      Prev = iTop;  
      iTop = iTop->next;      
    }
  }
  iTop = Res;  
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Печать односвязанного списка
// ----------------------------------------------------------

void FuncPrint(Node* iTop) {
  while (iTop) {
    std::cout << iTop->key;
    iTop=iTop->next;  
  }    
  std::cout << std::endl;  
}

int main() {
  Node *Chain = FuncInit("MAMA MILA RAMU");  // инициализируем
  FuncPrint(Chain);                          // печатаем
  FuncBackInsert(Chain,'!');                 // вставляем символ '!'
  FuncPrint(Chain);                          // печатаем
  FuncRemoveChar(Chain,'A');                 // удаляем все вхождения 'A'      
  FuncPrint(Chain);                          // печатаем
  FuncDestroy(Chain);                        // разрушаем оставшуюся структуру
  return 0;
}
```